# Java expression equivalence

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

For Java how is:

`long c = ((long)a << 32) | ((long)b & 0xFFFFFFFL);`

equivalent to

```
long c = (long)a << 32
c+=b
```

The bit mask as I understand it will give back the original number itself and the OR and the addition operation are not equivalent. How then do these two implementations always give the same answer?

Comment: To make them truly equivalent you need to do `c+= (b & 0xFFFFFFFL)` (I assume you meant to have 7Fs rather than 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the bits.

Suppose `int` is 1 byte (8 bits) and `long` is 2 bytes (16 bits).

The `a << 32` becomes `a << 8` and `0xFFFFFFFFL` becomes `0xFFFFL`:

Left part (`(long)a << 8`):

Start:

```
bits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
data: a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
```

Shift `a << 8`:

```
                      <-  shifted  ->
bits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
data: a a a a a a a a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Right part `((long)b & 0xFFFFL)`:

Start:

```
bits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
data: b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b
```

After `b & 0xFFFL`:

```
      <- & with 0  -> <- & with 1  ->
bits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
data: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 b b b b b b b b
```

And now `|` (note that `a` and `b` do not "touch" each other!):

```
bits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
data: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 b b b b b b b b

bits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
data: a a a a a a a a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Gives:

```
bits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
data: a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b
```

Note that this will probably work only for a subset of values (try positive and negative numbers), but the logic behind it is as I stated.

Comment: For anyone else facing the same problem the part that was tripping me up was the assumption I (wrongly) made that " & 0xFFFFFFFL" would return the same number. However it returns the lower 32 bits. After which it all makes sense. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise OR is equivalent to addition, if the operands do not have any common bits.

For example:

```
0x123456780000000 + 0x12345678 = 0x1234567812345678
0x123456780000000 | 0x12345678 = 0x1234567812345678
```

If you just shifted `a` 32 bits to the left, there will be 32 zero bits on the right. Assuming `b` has only 32 bits you can safely do OR instead of addition.

Comment: And assuming that `a` has only 32 bits, you can safely do the shift, in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

They're not equivalent (unless you restrict the possible values of `b`).

For example, if a == 1 and b == -1, the first expression results in `4563402751` and the second expression results in `4294967295`.

They will give the same result if you limit `b` to be >= `0` and <= `0xFFFFFFF` (which is `2^28 - 1`).

`(long)a << 32` (assuming `a` is of a smaller primitive type than `long`) shifts the bits of `a` 32 positions to the left.

Therefore if `a` was

```
                          xxx....xxxxxx
```

(long)a << 32 is

```
             xxx....xxxxxx000....000000
```

Now if you perform bitwise OR between this number and any non-negative `int`, you'll get the same result as adding those two numbers, since the low 32 bits of `(long)a << 32` are 0, so adding to it a number that only has 1 bits in its low 31 bits is the same as setting to 1 all the bits that are 1 in `(long)a << 32` and all the bits the are `1` in the second number (which is equivalent to bitwise OR).

Answer (score 1):

`((long)b & 0xFFFFFFFFL)` extracts the least significant 32 bits from `b`. `((long)a << 32)` creates a long where the least significant 32 bits are 0. This way, the OR is equivalent to `+=`.

I am not sure if this also works for negative values of b, though (two's complement).

Please note that `long` in Java has 64 bits.